# Can disjoint distributions be Computationally indistinguishable?

Tags: encryption, randomness

As mentioned in these notes [definition 2](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6830/2009fa/scribes/lec08.pdf)

> We say that $\{Xn\}_n$ and $\{Yn\}_n$ are computationally indistinguishable if,
> for all $\mathsf{nuPPT}$ $D$, there exists a negligible function $ε$ such that for
> every $n\in \mathcal{N}$, $|\Pr[t←X_n :D(t)=1]−\Pr[t←Y_n :D(t)=1]|\leq ε(n)$.

However, the definition also states that two disjoint distributions could be computationally indistinguishable. I not sure why that is true. Because if two distributions are disjoint then the $D$ who is given a sample that is either sampled from $X_n$ or $Y_n$ should be able to distinguish them with probability 1? Please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: It might be a possibility if it is computationally infeasible to determine which set a specific element belongs to (e.g. the quadratic residues modulo a composite of secret factorization vs. non qr's with Jacobi symbol 1)

Comment: @poncho okay, I am still confused, I am assuming that for "computationally infeasible to determine which set a specific element belongs to" the distribution should be overlapping. Also, can you clarify in computational indistinguishability definition, distinguisher is given a sample from distribution or distribution itself?